# How to calculate multiplication of probabilities when range is given?

Tags: probability

Assume that probability of $A$ is $0.6$ and probability of $B$ is at least $0.75$. Then how do I calculate the probability of both $A$ and $B$ happening together?

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are two events then

$$\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]=\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot \mathbb{P}[B\,|\, A]=\mathbb{P}[B]\cdot \mathbb{P}[A\,|\,B],$$

where $A\cap B$ is the event $A$ AND $B$ and $\mathbb{P}[A\,|\,B]$ is the probability of $A$ *given that $B$ is true*.

When $A$ and $B$ are *independent* (the truth of $A$ does not affect the truth of $B$) --- $\mathbb{P}[B\,|\,A]=\mathbb{P}[B]$ and so we have:

$$\mathbb{P}[A\cap B]=\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot \mathbb{P}[B].$$

I am guessing you might be coming from a finite-kind of a place so let us give an example where we can see where the multiplication comes from.

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the outcome of two dice rolls (these are independent). Now what is the probability of getting $X_2=1$ and $X_2=1$. Now you can list out 36 possibilities --- 6 TIMES 6 --- for the two dice rolls and only one of them corresponds to $X_1=X_2=1$. Now let $C$ be the event of a double one, $A$ be the event $X_1=1$ and $B$ be the event $X_2=1$. Note $C=A\cap B$ and

$$\mathbb{P}[C]=\frac{\text{# favourable outcomes}}{\text{# possible outcomes}}=\frac{1}{36}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\mathbb{P}[A]\cdot \mathbb{P}[B].$$

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate that from the information given.

As an illustration:  Imagine you choose a value N at random from 1, ..., 20.  at one extreme, suppose A is the event {N ≤ 12} and B is the event {N ≤ 15}.  Then A $\Rightarrow$ B and the probability of both is .6.
Now suppose A is the event {N ≤ 12} but B is now the event {N > 5}.  In this case, the only over lap is N = 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12 so the probability of both occurring is $\frac{7}{20}$